# Fermentation of bananas

Tags: biotechnology, fermentation

I may have access to huge quantities of freshly picked bananas. Searching the web, I have found that the sugar content of the average banana is 14g of fructose (could stand to be corrected on this) which should in principle allow for fermentation. The bananas are in no way processed. My questions now are:

(1) How suitable are bananas for ethanol or methanol fermentation?

(2) How exactly is the fermentation workflow? I presume the bananas would be chopped?

(3) considering point (2) what effect would the banana skin have on the fermentation process? Would it be better to ferment the whole fruit including skins or remove the skin before fermentation?

Hope someone can help

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. I edited your question to improve the structuring and clarify a bit. Please feel free to further edit or re-edit.

Comment: How to make banana wine seems like a good start: http://www.celebrationgeneration.com/blog/2011/10/13/how-to-make-homemade-banana-wine/comment-page-1/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question isn't about biology, even if it induced a solid answer.

Answer (score 3):

Fruit Moonshine is quite desirable :)

Peel the bananas. Good workflow here:

http://www.moonshiners.club/banana-moonshine-recipe/

It takes considerable work especially in large quantities. Furthermore, check legality and read up on methanol poisoning.  Don't poison yourself!

[image]

Comment: That's impressive!

Comment: Is it too late to change my username to Banana Moonshine?